# Help me figure out how to come up with the start of this proof on my own?

Tags: trigonometry

So the statement is $$4 + \sin^2x \geq 6\sin2x,\quad\forall x \in \Bbb R.$$
Now the start of this proof says

"We know that $(3\sin x - 2\cos^2x)^2 \geq 0$."

And then they just expanded this to get the starting statement. I get why this works but how the heck do you come up with the beginning statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes - depending on the author, their experience, etc. - they like to start proofs with moves like that which seemingly come out of nowhere, even though they end up implying the desired result.

Usually, particularly in a textbook or something, it would be nice for them to elaborate on "why we start with this" and all that, but oh well.

Without seeing the full proof it's hard to say why that might have been chosen though.

Comment: You can't do it because it's false. If $x=\pi /4$ then $6\sin 2x=6>4+1>4+1/\sqrt 2\,=4+\sin x$.

Comment: My first thought was to substitute $(1-\cos 2x)/2$ for $\sin^2x,$ and $ 2x=y,$ to get an inequality of the form $A\geq B\cos y+C\sin y.$ The largest value of  $B\cos y +C \sin y$ is $\sqrt {B^2+C^2}\;.$

Comment: There is an error in my first comment . The last line should be $6\sin 2x=6>4+\frac {1}{2}=4+\sin^2 x$.